# Assimp calculating bones

Tags: c++, opengl, assimp

Ive been trying to load my skinned collada mesh using assimp for the last few days but am having an extremely hard time. Currently I am just trying to render it in its normal "pose" without any transformations or animations but the mesh comes very deformed. I think the problem lies in my bones, not my weights so I am only posting the bone section.

Here is my bone loading code:

```
// this is done for every bone in a for loop:
Bone new_bone;

new_bone.name = std::string(bone->mName.data);

aiMatrix4x4 b_matrix = bone->mOffsetMatrix;
aiMatrix4x4 g_inv = scene->mRootNode->mTransformation;
g_inv.Inverse(); // according to a tutorial, you have to multiply by inverse root
b_matrix = b_matrix * g_inv;
memcpy(new_bone.matrix, &b_matrix, sizeof(float) * 16);

Bones.push_back(new_bone);
```

Then I simply send this to my shader with

```
glUniformMatrix4fv(MatrixArray, bone_count, GL_FALSE, &MATRIX_BUFFER[0][0][0]);
```

And apply it in the vertex shader with:

```
mat4 Bone = V_MatrixArray[int(Indicies[0])] * Weights[0];
Bone += V_MatrixArray[int(Indicies[1])] * Weights[1];
Bone += V_MatrixArray[int(Indicies[2])] * Weights[2];
Bone += V_MatrixArray[int(Indicies[3])] * Weights[3];

vec4 v = Bone * vec4(Vertex, 1);
gl_Position = MVP * vec4(v.xyz, 1);
```

This code mostly works, however my mesh is very deformed.... It looks like this:

[image]

According to the reserach ive done so far:

- I do not need to transpose my matrices since assimp uses OpenGL column major
- I do not need to read the nodes of the scene yet since they are for 
  animation

Please correct me if I am mistaken about these last 2 things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it. Turns out you **DO** need to read the nodes, even for a simple bind pose without animation. For any future readers with this issue, each bones matrix = root_node_inverse * matrix concatenated from node heirechy * bone offset matrix.

Comment: Do you still have the code for that project? I am struggeling with similar problems :(

Comment: @Andrea yup I still have it :), its right here: https://github.com/Jas03x/GL_Engine/blob/master/src/ColladaLoader.cpp, https://github.com/Jas03x/GL_Engine/blob/master/src/Animation.h, https://github.com/Jas03x/GL_Engine/blob/master/src/Bone.h. Unfortunately I don't have my shader because I deleted it sorry. Its not perfect but it works. Let me know if you have any questions :)

Comment: Some of the links Jas posted have been broken by changes to the repository. Here's a set of links to the code as it existed when they were originally posted: [ColladaLoader.cpp](https://github.com/Jas03x/GL_GameKit/blob/436a7921f0c342de681732f6dd850277626fc03a/src/ColladaLoader.cpp), [Animation.h](https://github.com/Jas03x/GL_GameKit/blob/436a7921f0c342de681732f6dd850277626fc03a/src/Animation.h), [Bone.h](https://github.com/Jas03x/GL_GameKit/blob/436a7921f0c342de681732f6dd850277626fc03a/src/Bone.h).